# how to remove extra margin between two cells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I would like to remove extra space between two cells in UICollection.

[image]

[image]

I find some solutions but or not works fine or lan programming is `object-c`.

Answer (score 1):

Change "min spacing" property for cells in Collection view to 0. In story board, Click on the collection view and check the following properties in the inspector and change the min spacing. [image]